# MPChart values overriding in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I have a MPChart and I am setting the values like this

```
lineChart.legend.isEnabled = false
        lineChart.description.isEnabled = false

        val entryList = arrayListOf<Entry>()
        val sortedList = stockGraphResponse?.prices?.sortedWith(compareBy {
            it?.date
        })

        for (i in 0 until sortedList?.size!!) {
            val item = Utils.replaceCommaInNumber(sortedList[i]?.price!!).toFloat()
            entryList.add(Entry(sortedList[i]?.date?.toFloat()!!, item))

        }

        val lineDataSet = LineDataSet(entryList,"")
        lineDataSet.setDrawCircles(false)
        lineDataSet.setDrawFilled(true)

        val lineData = LineData(lineDataSet)
        lineChart.data = lineData
        lineChart.setDrawBorders(true)


        val xAxis = lineChart.xAxis
        xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(CustomFormatter())
        xAxis.setLabelCount(5,true)

        val yAxis = lineChart.axisLeft


        val yRight = lineChart.axisRight
        yRight.isEnabled = false

        lineChart.isAutoScaleMinMaxEnabled = true
        lineChart.invalidate()
```

And the result is this graph
[image]

I am setting 5 for label count in xAxis and I am getting 5 labels but then the values are being plotted like that and so they are overlapping. I tried using granularity but still the same. How can I streamline this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks